# Java: Cleanly Redirect Exception to String

Tags: java, string, error-handling

In Java, sometimes I get an exception parsing user input. Instead of printing a stack trace, I want it to "cleanly" redirect the output to a string. Example (uses LuaJ):

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: [string "jhkfchyufjhdnxvk,gh'bnmcvk,fvjmfk,xdcfsdkckucfdxfds,ie(); "]:1: unfinished string
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.lexerror(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.read_string(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.llex(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.next(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.str_checkname(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.singlevar(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.primaryexp(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.suffixedexp(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.assignment(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.exprstat(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.statement(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.statlist(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LexState.mainfunc(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LuaC.luaY_parser(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.compiler.LuaC.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.Globals.compilePrototype(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.Globals.loadPrototype(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.Globals.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.Globals.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.luaj.vm2.Globals.load(Unknown Source)
    at net.snugglesstuff.LeoBot.LuaThread.run(LuaThread.java:25)
```

What the output should be:

```
[string "jhkfchyufjhdnxvk,gh'bnmcvk,fvjmfk,xdcfsdkckucfdxfds,ie(); "]:1: unfinished string
```

Comment: use log4j for getting errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can catch the exception and print `exception.getMessage()`.

```
try {
  ... parsing code ...
}
catch (Exception exc) { // change this to catch the specific type of exceptions relevant to the parsing
    System.out.println(exc.getMessage()); // or redirect the message to a file
}
```

Comment: And note that you can, eg, write the exception stack trace to a log file, in case you might want to look at it later.